# How can I define the tensor product in the tensor algebra?

Tags: tensor-products

If $V$ is a vector spaces over a field $K$,
$$
V_{r , s} = \left(\bigotimes_{i = 1}^r V\right) \otimes \left(\bigotimes_{j = 1}^s V^*\right)\mbox{,}
$$
where $r , s \in \mathbb{N} \cup \{0\}$, and $V_{0 , 0} = K$. I have found the next statement:
$$
T(V) = \bigoplus_{r , s \in \mathbb{N} \cup \{0\}} V_{r , s} \quad \mbox{ is an algebra on } K\mbox{.}
$$
If we take $u = {(u_{(r , s)})}_{r , s = 0}^{\infty}$ and $v = {(v_{(r , s)})}_{r , s = 0}^{\infty}$ in $T(V)$, can I define $u \otimes v$ by $u \otimes v = {(u_{(r , s)} \otimes v_{(r , s)})}_{r , s = 0}^{\infty}$, where, for each $r , s \in \mathbb{N} \cup \{0\}$,
$$
u_{(r , s)} \otimes v_{(r , s)} = \left(\bigotimes_{i = 0}^r u_i\right) \otimes \left(\bigotimes_{i = 0}^r v_i\right) \otimes \left(\bigotimes_{j = 0}^s u_j^*\right) \otimes \left(\bigotimes_{j = 0}^s v_j^*\right)?
$$
The vectors $u_{(r , s)}$ and $v_{(r , s)}$ are in $V_{r , s}$ and are given by
$$
u_{(r , s)} = \left(\bigotimes_{i = 0}^r u_i\right) \otimes \left(\bigotimes_{j = 0}^s u_j^*\right) \quad \mbox{ and } \quad v_{(r , s)} = \left(\bigotimes_{i = 0}^r v_i\right) \otimes \left(\bigotimes_{j = 0}^s v_j^*\right)\mbox{.}
$$
I have searched how it's defined in many books (like Warner: Foundations of Differentiable Manifolds and Lie Groups), but I always find the same: the tensor product $\otimes : T(V) \times T(V) \to T(V)$ is given by
$$
u \otimes v = \left(\bigotimes_{i = 0}^{r_1} u_i\right) \otimes \left(\bigotimes_{j = 0}^{r_2} v_j\right) \otimes \left(\bigotimes_{k = 0}^{s_1} u_k^*\right) \otimes \left(\bigotimes_{l = 0}^{s_2} v_j^*\right) \in V_{r_1 + r_2 , s_1 + s_2}
$$
if
$$
u = \left(\bigotimes_{i = 0}^{r_1} u_i\right) \otimes \left(\bigotimes_{k = 0}^{s_1} u_k^*\right) \in V_{r_1 , s_1} \quad \mbox{ and } \quad v = \left(\bigotimes_{j = 0}^{r_2} v_j\right) \otimes \left(\bigotimes_{l = 0}^{s_2} v_l^*\right) \in V_{r_2 , s_2}\mbox{,}
$$
but I don't understand this definition because I think that the elements in $T(V)$ have infinite coordinates, as (according to my thought)
$$
\bigoplus_{n = 1}^{\infty} V_n = \{{(v_n)}_{n = 1}^{\infty} : v_n \in V_n \mbox{ for all } n = 1 , 2 , \ldots\}
$$
if ${\{V_n\}}_{n = 1}^{\infty}$ is a collection of vector spaces over $K$. Can you help me to realize myself what's my mistake? Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In the direct sum, only finitely many coordinates can be non-zero. This is the difference between the direct sum and the direct product.

The "coordinate" $r,s$ is just the part of $T(V)$ which is additively generated by guys of the form $(v_{1}\otimes \ldots \otimes v_{r})\otimes (v_{1}^{*}\otimes \ldots \otimes v_{s}^{*})$. So the direct sum here means that you don't allow expressions of the form $v_{1}\otimes v_{2}\otimes \ldots $, with infinitely many $\otimes $ symbols. So the given definition is fine.

Comment: But though it happens, the elements in $T(V)$ have infinite coordinates, don't they?

Comment: I think that the only thing that it says is: for all $v \in T(V)$ there exist $r , s \in \mathbb{N} \cup \{0\}$ such that
$$
v = \left(\bigotimes_{i = 0}^r v_i\right) \otimes \left(\bigotimes_{j = r + 1}^{\infty} 0\right) \otimes \left(\bigotimes_{k = 0}^s v_k^*\right) \otimes \left(\bigotimes_{l = s + 1}^{\infty} 0\right)\mbox{.}
$$

Comment: Let me elaborate a bit the answer maybe

Comment: But the equality
$$
\left(\bigotimes_{i = 0}^r v_i\right) \otimes \left(\bigotimes_{j = r + 1}^{\infty} 0\right) \otimes \left(\bigotimes_{k = 0}^s v_k^*\right) \otimes \left(\bigotimes_{l = s + 1}^{\infty} 0\right) = \left(\bigotimes_{i = 0}^r v_i\right) \otimes \left(\bigotimes_{k = 0}^s v_k^*\right)
$$
is false, right?

Comment: What do you mean by $\bigotimes_{j=r+1}^{\infty} 0$? I guess you can make sense out of it, but I don't think you actually want to (see for example [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/11767/infinite-tensor-products) question on MathOverflow). An element in $T(V)$ can only have finitely many $\otimes $ symbols. This number can be arbitrarily large (and this is why we need the infinite direct sum), but never infinite.

Comment: I compare this situation with points $(x , y)$ and $(x , y , 0)$ in ${\mathbb{R}}^2$ and in ${\mathbb{R}}^3$, respectively (probably the comparison isn't the best but it can ilustrate that the above equality is false I think).

Comment: As I said, the above equality is neither true nor false, it is just meaningless (unless you give it a precise meaning). In that comparason, the point $(x,y)$ would be something like $x_{1}+y_{1}\otimes y_{2}$. If you really want to think in coordinates (and let me forget about the duals $v^{*}$ to make this discussion simpler) you should think of an element $(x_{i})_{i\in \mathbb{N}}\in T(V)$ as a sequence of elements where $x_{i}\in \bigotimes_{j=1}^{i} V$. Such an $x_{i}$ is in turn of the form $\sum_{\alpha=1}^{l} v_{\alpha, 1}\otimes \ldots \otimes v_{\alpha, i}$.